# Travis CI doesn`t see my changes in github files

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have a github repository in the organization and the Travis file has been changed to:

```
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk8

mvn installation
mvn test
```

however, it looked different and contained a ant test command that was removed.
Recently, when I try to restart a job, do the following again:

> Ant test 0,23 USD Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! The
>   construction was unsuccessful The "ant test" command ended at 1.

and in the config view there is no current travis file with github.

What's the problem? why Travis doesnt see my changes in github files?